# What is the Traitor's Motive?

Tags: plot-explanation, air-force-one

In the movie [*Air Force One*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118571/) the terrorists use the help of a traitor from inside the crew/staff. But what was his motivation for helping the terrorists?

This is really a key development in the movie. It's the only way they could get weapons on the plane like that and it is not explained AT ALL.

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118571/faq?ref_=tt_faq_1#.2.1.2

Comment: @Dan You should put that in (with a quote) as an answer

Comment: @chistian's edit really gives the question a meaning.

Answer (score 6):

Since *Dan* provided a very good answer in his comment but refused to add it as a proper answer, I'll post it for that sake of completeness:

The [IMDB FAQ](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118571/faq?ref_=tt_faq_1#.2.1.2) for the movie gives a good explanation for his motivation (and the reason it wasn't actually shown):

> Why did Agent Gibbs turn rogue?
>
> In the script, Agent Gibbs was a CIA spook who was angry at his
>   country. He knew the terrorists from his CIA days, so they included
>   him in their operation. This scene was considered too long to tell, so
>   it was cut from the film.

Comment: I hate when they cut such scenes from movies ... I'm sure there was something else less "quintessential" to the movie which could have been cut. At the very least they could have given us a hint as to the motivation.